# Position:absolute creating messing up grid flow

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm trying to make a grid with css from which, when clicked, a div can "break out" of using position:absolute, so that it can be moved around above the grid without messing with aforementioned grid. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5PPc/). As you can see, when clicked the position is set to absolute, but henceforth destroys the grid structure around it instead of simply floating above it. I've tryed using `z-index`, but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to `.icon_wrapper`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E5PPc/1/)